# flutter display 3d objects flutter_3d_obj

Tags: flutter, canvas, 3d, blender

I have managed to display 3d objects on flutter using [/flutter_3d_obj](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_3d_obj). I'm now trying to get coordinates of a click point in flutter. How do i go about it.Or what is the best way to display 3d objects in flutter? and have the ability to get coordinates of a point.

Comment: If this plugin does not offer a way to do it, then there is no way to get the 3D coordinates of a tap - you would have to add that functionality to the plugin in that case.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot is there way to do it..even if its native

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your 3Dmodel Widget with a [GestureDectector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) Widget and use the `onTapDownDetail` property to listen to touch position

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_3d_obj/flutter_3d_obj.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('3D Touchable Model'),
        ),
        body: Touch3DModel());
  }
}

class Touch3DModel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return Touch3DModelState();
  }
}

class Touch3DModelState extends State<Touch3DModel> {
  double obj_width = 100;
  double obj_height = 100; 
  double x_coord = 100.0;
  double y_coord = 100.0;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      x_coord = localOffset.dx;
      y_coord = localOffset.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
      child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
        Container(color: Colors.grey),
        Positioned(
          child: Object3D(
            size: const Size(obj_width, obj_height),
            path: "assets/file.obj",
            asset: true,
          ),
          left: x_coord - obj_width / 2,  // To offset the object possitioning from top left of the object to the center. 
          top: y_coord - obj_height / 2,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: Using flutter_3d_obj will require that you have a 3d obj that you built with something like blender or a similar tool.

Credit to [aptik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559098/aptik)